# What is a Toronto Transit Commission code 299 or 506?

Tags: trains, public-transport, canada, terminology, toronto

I heard this on the TTC (Toronto's subway system) public address system: "506 Eglinton." What is this about? Any enlightened folks out there, who may have an
answer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about subway operations.

Comment: @DJClayworth Is travelling by subway off-topic?

Comment: They say that all the time.  "506 Eglinton, 506 Eglinton, please call control."

Comment: @gerrit is it always 506?  In New York, they use the train's departure time as an identifier.

Comment: @phoog I don't remember for sure, but I'm pretty sure they do not use the train's departure time in Toronto and that it's always 506.

Answer (score 4):

[From the Googles](http://transit.toronto.on.ca/subway/5007.shtml):

> 299 Supervisor - Line Mechanics

506 is not listed, but [this](http://www.cptdb.ca/index.php?showtopic=1805) claims it's "janitor".

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that codes used in the public address system are job description codes.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this [article](http://transit.toronto.on.ca/spare/0023.shtml) on Transit Toronto reveals the job code:

> 506 PLANT MAINTENANCE DEPARTMENT Janitors

If you're wondering about "**Eglinton**", it is a [subway station](http://ttc.ca/Subway/Stations/Eglinton/station.jsp) off Yonge St.

So when you hear 506 Eglinton, they're calling for janitors and if this user is to believed on [reddit](https://www.google.ca/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/toronto/comments/gnptb/any_ttc_employees_here_whats_it_mean_when_they/):

> Laxxium • Apr 12, 2011, 6:05 AM
>   506 is the main janitor...
>   504 is the secondary Janitor if there is one on duty. 502 is the Janitor's supervisor.
>   So if you hear 506 or 504 x 2 or x3 and then a 502, someone's in trouble for not answering their call.
>   I know this cuz I was a summer student janitor.

The 502 code appears to be updated since this comment.

I also lived in Toronto and still visit monthly. They're calling for whoever is on duty at that station.